# temporarily block the UI, and run a callback

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

For sake of simplicity, I want an all purpose function to block the UI (ie click events, but maybe not hover etc.) , and optionally run a callback when it's done.  So far I have this:

```
blockedUI=false;
function blockUI(milliseconds,callback)
{
    blockedUI=true;
    if (callback===undefined)
        setTimeout(function(){blockedUI=false;},milliseconds);
    else
        setTimeout(function(callback){blockedUI=false;callback();},milliseconds);
}

function itemClicked(item)
{
   if(blockedUI)return;

   //handle click
}

blockUI(1000,function{alert("UI is now available");});
```

basically, whenever I handle something, I'll check if the UI is curently "blocked".   My specific problem here is actually that I can't figure out how to pass the callback function along to the anonymous function that I'm passing to setTimeout.

The real question is, how can I pass the callback parameter and call it in the body of the setTimeout anonymous function parameter

Comment: just append an invisible div layer over everything, that will do what you want pretty easily.  just remove it after your done.

Comment: ok sure but then I'd still want to be able to make a blockUI function that accepts a callback.  how would I do a timeout then call that callback

Comment: If you are using JQuery you can use the plugin called BlockUI. http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: So, do you have the parameter that you want to send to the callback at the time of invoking `setTimeout` or not? You have a few options either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify additional parameters to `setTimeout`, these will be passed into the function you provide to `setTimeout` when the function is called -- thus,

```
setTimeout(function(foo) { alert(foo); }, 100, "green")
```

would alert "green" after the timeout elapses. You could pass the callback into your function like that.

That having been said, in your case, you shouldn't need to pass the callback into the anonymous function at all -- it should be in scope from the anonymous function since it is declared inside of blockUI. I think this is the better way to go, since it's both clearer and better supported by older browsers.

Comment: thanks. you were right. my error was I had originally named the global variable blockUI the same as my function blockUI, so when I got the error, I assumed you couldn't just call a callback that was in the original scope.  Also, the info about extra parameters is very helpful

Comment: FYI, these extra parameters for `setTimeout()` do not work in many version of IE (such as IE9 and before).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the callback parameter into the `setTimeout()` callback.  It is available in the `setTimeout()` callback as it was passed because it is in the parent scope and thus available to any inline child function.

So, you can do this:

```
blockedUI = false;
function blockUI(milliseconds, callback) {
    blockedUI = true;
    if (callback === undefined) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            blockedUI = false;
        }, milliseconds);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            blockedUI = false; 
            // the callback argument from above is available here
            // without doing anything special
            // arguments from parent functions are automatically usable
            callback();
        }, milliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I knew it works that way in C#, but I didn't realize javascript would also "capture" the outer vars.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - and this works in all browsers, unlike the extra arguments to `setTimeout()`.  This seems like a better and safer option.

Comment: yes, that's actually what I'm now doing. @Chris W pointed it out first, so I tried and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - but I don't even get at least an upvote for showing you the exact code you can use and for only recommending things that work in all browsers.  I don't usually pander for upvotes, but I really don't like Chris' answer because it looks like the main point of his answer is to recommend something that doesn't work in IE9 and isn't the simplest way of solving the problem.

Comment: you are right about it not focusing on the "solution" but it actually focused on my actual question, which was about passing parameters.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - I tend to focus on the actual best solution to someone's problem rather than their literal question which is usually more valuable to all.  In this case, passing parameters to `setTimeout()` is simply not what you should do.  You should just use the argument that is already in scope.  Anyway, thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I'll upvote you too -- I focused on the literal question, but I completely agree with you that using the variable already in scope is the better solution.